# How Can I filter my request to a certain cabin class in Sabre Bargain Finder Max REST API?

Tags: json, sabre

Looking to Filter my search to a certain cabin class, I put in "Economy" in the CabinPref section below but it is giving me an invalid request error.

This is my request:

```
   {
   "OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ":{
      "TPA_Extensions":{
         "IntelliSellTransaction":{
            "RequestType":{
               "Name":"200ITINS"
            }
         }
      },
      "TravelPreferences":{
         "TPA_Extensions":{
            "NumTrips":{

            },
            "DataSources":{
               "NDC":"Disable",
               "LCC":"Disable",
               "ATPCO":"Enable"
            }
         },
         "CabinPref":{
            "Cabin":"Economy",
            "PreferLevel":"Preferred"
         }
      },
      "OriginDestinationInformation":[
         {
            "RPH":"0",
            "DepartureDateTime":"2019-11-21T00:00:00",
            "OriginLocation":{
               "LocationCode":"YHZ"
            },
            "DestinationLocation":{
               "LocationCode":"YTO"
            }
         }
      ],
      "POS":{
         "Source":[
            {
               "RequestorID":{
                  "Type":"1",
                  "ID":"1",
                  "CompanyName":{
                     "Code":"TN"
                  }
               },
               "PseudoCityCode":"H78H"
            }
         ]
      },
      "Version":"1",
      "TravelerInfoSummary":{
         "SeatsRequested":[
            1
         ],
         "PriceRequestInformation":{
            "CurrencyCode":"INR"
         },
         "AirTravelerAvail":[
            {
               "PassengerTypeQuantity":[
                  {
                     "Code":"ADT",
                     "Quantity":1
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Response:

```
{
   "status":"NotProcessed",
   "errorCode":"INVALIDREQ",
   "message":"[{\"level\":\"error\",\"schema\":{\"loadingURI\":\"#\",\"pointer\":\"/definitions/org.opentravel.ota._2003._05.AirSearchPrefsType/properties/CabinPref\"},\"instance\":{\"pointer\":\"/OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ/TravelPreferences/CabinPref\"},\"domain\":\"validation\",\"keyword\":\"type\",\"message\":\"instance type (object) does not match any allowed primitive type (allowed: [\\\"array\\\"])\",\"found\":\"object\",\"expected\":[\"array\"]}]",
   "type":"Validation",
   "timeStamp":"2019-07-23T10:00:54.624-05:00"
}
```

Any idea why this is invalid?

Answer (score 0):

In "Cabin" you have "Economy".
You need to use the cabin code, not the cabin name. From the Sabre documentation:

This element specifies preferred cabin type for flexible fare leg. A cabin is either Premium First (P), First (F), Premium Business (J), Business (C), Premium Economy (S) or Economy (Y)

So in your case, you should use "Y" instead of "Economy"

Comment: Weird, I tried that and got the same result, do you see anything else wrong with the request?

Answer (score 0):

CabinPref accepts array. Please try:

```
"CabinPref": [
  {
    "Cabin": "Economy"
  }
],
```

Hope it helps